# Can't get Kendo UI TreeView to read children in JSON data correctly

Tags: kendo-ui

http://jsfiddle.net/N8Svz/5/

I'm sure I must be doing something kind of dumb; this seems like a textbook usage of HeirarchicalDataSource as far as I can tell.

```
var domtree = [{
    "id": "linear1",
    "element-class": "LinearLayout",
    "children": [{
        "id": "static1",
        "element-class": "Static"
    }, {
        "id": "static2",
        "element-class": "Static",
        "children": [{
            "id": "static3",
            "element-class": "Static"
        }]
    }, {
        "id": "4",
        "element-class": "Error"
    }]
}];

var inline = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: domtree,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "id",
            children: "children"
        }
    }
});

$("#navtree").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: inline,
    dataTextField: "id"
});
```

A big thank you to anyone who can point out what I'm doing wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just change the field `children` to `items`.

here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nn007/N8Svz/6/

Comment: Hmm, fascinating.  I had the HeirarchicalDataSource set up to use "children" as the field name for child nodes, whereas "items" is the default.

As it turns out, the string "children" specifically doesn't work, but any other value as far as I can tell does.

Comment: yes ,i also has this problem, i think this is a bug. i use the latest 2016 version

Answer (score 0):

If you add the schema property like this it may work. You are telling the hierarchical datasource what the key for children is. Something like this:

schema: { model: { children: "children" } }